# How to force VS2008 to "Generate Create Script to Project" to multiple files when multiple stored procedures are selected?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, code-generation, database-project

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Developer Edition and I've created a Database Project and want to generate CREATE scripts from my database and save them in my database project.

It works just fine when I select a single stored procedure in the Database and click "Generate Create Script to Project". The problem is that when I select MULTIPLE PROCS - it outputs the script into the single file.

Is there a way to force the output into the multiple files (one file per stored procedure)?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's [Database Publishing Wizard](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=56E5B1C5-BF17-42E0-A410-371A838E570A&displaylang=en) will generate create scripts for procedures.  I don't have SQL Server installed here at work so I can't confirm this, but I think you can generate multiple files.

If I remember correctly, the user interface is a little different when you run this application from the Start menu than when you run it from within Visual Studio's Server Explorer.